# When would a HTable.batch() operation result in an InterruptedException?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

In the Java HBase API [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#batch%28java.util.List%29) for the `HTable`'s `batch` method, it states that it can throw a `InterrupedException`.

Under which circumstances would this occur?

Can I make any assumptions about whether or not some or all of the actions in the batch were successful? I.e., should I assume that the batch operation was only partially successful and do a manual rollback by deleting all the row keys in the batch (assuming all the actions were puts) ?